# How to use classnames lib with conditional and dynamic classes

Tags: css, reactjs, class-names

I started using `classnames` lib and it's pretty simple and neat until I hit this case.

I want to make an expandable row animation. Idea is simple - conditionally add class that would add animation to the open row. The hight of the expanded row is dynamic in my case.

Here's my simplified React component

```
// some code

const expanded = {
    maxHeight: heightProp,
    transition: 'max-height 1s ease-out';
  };

  const expandable = classnames({
    [styles.expandableContainer]: true,
    [expanded]: isExpanded,
  });

return (
   <tr ref={rowRef} className={expandable}></td>
)

// some code
```

CSS file

```
.expandableContainer {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-in;
}
```

For right now it gives me as a result `class="expandableContainer [object Object]"` in expanded state. Where's the issue here? Why it's `objectObject`?

If this `heightProp` wouldn't be dynamic it would be just

```
const expandable = classnames({
    [styles.expandableContainer]: true,
    [styles.expanded]: isExpanded,
  });
```

But looks like I don't know how to deal with css defined inside a component.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok the answer would be don't use `classnames`, use just

`<tr className={styles.expandableContainer} style={isExpanded ? expanded : null}></tr>`